# iCloud Messages macOS Not Available

Tags: macos, icloud, messages

I upgraded to my iPhone and Watch (iOS and watchOS 11.4, respectively).  I've already had iMessages turned on and have been using it for years.

I enabled iCloud Messages on the iPhone but the Messages on my Watch kept showing a green bubble from my blue bubble people.

I went to [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208532) to ensure I was turning iCloud Messages on correctly and I verified my iPhone settings were correct.

The problem is with the Mac.  There's no iCloud Messages checkbox available in `Messages -> Preferences -> Accounts`.  I verified the macOS update was successful and I didn't get any error messages during the upgrade.

Is it just me (others can see the iCloud Messages checkbox) or has it not rolled-out to everyone yet?  Do I need to be more patient and wait for the feature to become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this site](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/messages-icloud-is-working-for-ios-devices-only-right-now-not-macs-0185000/), Apple didn't push out macOS 10.13.5 yet.  That's why I don't have the option in Messages.

I got a Mac update today and I thought it included iCloud Messages.  It turns out that it was just an iTunes update.

We'll have to wait a little long to get iCloud Messages on our Macs.

Answer (score 3):

10.13.5 out now and solved this problem.